# How to attach softkeyboard event

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

**Update:**

This is the WTF of Android SDK, if targetSdkVersion is 15, no problem.
But after 16, will not respond to setOnKeyListener.

and in targetSdkVersion 15, it will raise **Twice**.
hey beee u android.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

**In particular, the default software keyboard will never send any key event to any application targetting Jelly Bean or later, and will only send events for some presses of the delete and return keys to applications targetting Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier.**

**Update:**

Please show me why you have to vote down my post.

**Question**

Could I know what the soft keyboard input?

Not `OnKeyListener`, it only for hardware keyboard.
I need softkeyboard.

Not `TextWatcher`, it only for changed text.
For example, in EditText, when `getSelectionStart` is 0, i click softkeyboard delete button. There is nothing changed.

my code:
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="www.ilivebox.demo"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name="MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

layout 
main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/memo_text_segment"
        android:hint="add new here.."
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

MyActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText mEditText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.memo_text_segment);
        mEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                Log.d("KeyCode: " + keyCode + " " + event.getCharacters(), "..........");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you wana use TextWatcher?? If not editText, what r u using soft keyboard for?

Comment: For example, I have a LinearLayout, the layout is as follows :
-------------
ImageView
EditText
-------------
When I EditText no text can be deleted , I need to remove the previous ImageView
This time , the focus in the EditText , I need to know whether to press the Del .

Answer (score 1):

You catch the KeyEvent and then check its keycode.

```
if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
```

Comment: and where should i add this code?
in EditText.setOnKeyListener ?
If this is the case , please check my question.

Comment: Sorry, please forgive my ignorance, but I really don't know what you want to express.

Comment: To get the key pressed you have to intercept events from users.

Comment: ok, back to my question.where should i add this code? in EditText.setOnKeyListener? LinearLayout.dispatchKeyEvent? onKeyUp?onKeyDown?Or the other ?i know i have to intercept event from softkeyboard, and my question is ,i try to catch it in EditText.setOnKeyListener, but it not work, and i google it, somebody say , hey setOnKeyListener just for hardware keyboard, and i dont know what is for softkeyboard, and i post my question in here.and ,where should i add your code to?

Comment: and to @mjosh,View.setOnKeyListener 's doc
[link]-> (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html) <- 
**Key presses in software keyboards will generally NOT trigger this method,**